# How to Add property _value pairs to a txt file and sort them alphabetically

Tags: matlab

I want to add property-values pair in a txt file which contains property-values pairs and the properties should be sorted alphabetically, where a property is between square brackets and its value in the line below. This is an example file: On top of that i want to ignore the comment lines started with '#'.

```
#
[system]
# 
programming 
#
[information] 
#
application
```

Like:-

```
function [] = updateFile( fileName,property,propertyValue )

% all inputs in strings
%
rfh = fopen( fileName, 'r' ); % read handle
tname = tempname(); % temporary file name
wfh = fopen( tname, 'w' )
```

In this example, ´system´ is a property and ´programming´ its value. The same way, ´information´ is another property and ´application´ its value.

I want to call my function with a property-value pair and update the txt file with the new property-value pairs.

Comment: Looking for someone to help me with the above one . :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are updating a file you should open it in "append" mode. You use the `sort` function to sort your data. Assuming the variables `property` and `propertyValue` are cell arrays, your code would look something like this

```
function [] = updateFile( fileName,property,propertyValue )

% all inputs in strings

fid = fopen(fileName, 'a' ); % file handle
[property_sorted,sort_index] = sort(property); % sort file
for count = 1:length(sort_index)
    fprintf(fid,'%s\n%s\n',property_sorted(count),propertyValue(sort_index(count)));
end

fclose(fid);
```

See the documentation for sort (`doc sort`) for more information.